# Is there any way to keep serverside sessions with JWT?

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io, jwt

I'm using JWT on my application and I define my claims like so:

```
const claims = {
   iss: process.env.DOMAIN, // The URL of your service
   sub: user.email, // The UID of the user in your system
   scope: "game",
   email: user.email
};
```

While this works properly, I don't like the idea of adding session data into claims object which makes it available on the frontend too. Instead, I want to keep certain session data on backend only, such as:

```
nJwt.verify(socket.handshake.query.token, app.get("jwt.secret"), (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) return;
    // pseudo code
    Session.of(decoded.body.email).get("cheater_accuracy"); // 0.48912715
});
```

The ideal approach for me would be keeping claims object as simple as this:

```
const claims = {
   iss: process.env.DOMAIN,
   sub: user.email,
   scope: "game",
   email: user.email
};
```

and keeping every session data on backend only, which can be referenced by token at any time.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Redis](http://redis.io/) to store your session data and access it by your token. Use [SET](http://redis.io/commands/set) to store your value upon issuing a token and use [GET](http://redis.io/commands/get) to get it back upon veriying.

Answer (score 0):

I think express-session should works, the usage is typically:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({secret: 'yoursecretword'}));


app.get('/some-page', function(req, res) {
   req.session.lastPage = '/laspage';
   res.send('Some response');
});
```

take a look: http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions